# Best practice in keeping `$watch` functions away from your controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I tried to find some good examples on best practice in moving `$watch` functions from a controller to a factory, for example.

What I have found is that actually there isn't a unanimous opinion on what's best to do. I've seen examples of injection the `$rootScope` into a factory and `$watch`ing for value changes there.

Another suggestion is to avoid them whenever possible, and to use `ngChange` instead on the element itself, for example:

```
<div ng-model="foo.bar" ng-change="updateValue(foo.bar)"></div>
```

What is your proposed way? I've been putting `$watch`es in my controllers ever since I started learning AngularJS but now I want to embrace best practice approaches, trying to make and keep my controllers as thin as possible.

Comment: If you are looking for best practices in general I've to point you to this article http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/04/19/5-angularjs-antipatterns-and-pitfalls/ then when it comes to watches they can be usually avoided. I don't know specific of your work and when the watches occur so I can't really answer this question. The only place I can think of is where user make changes and you want to watch for them, if the change happens on your side you should be able to do it without watches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess where to put `$watch` heavily depends on the use-case scenario. The most important thing to be careful about `$watch` is not to do any hard-work inside the handle function especially if what you are watching is changing a lot; that would highly damper your performance. And be sure that in your handle function you don't change something else which is already being watched as this will cause a chain of change updates.

If you are sure that the variable you are watching can only be changed from one place, it is better idea to use `ng-change` rather than `$watch` as you already know the place where it gets changed.

It is generally good practice not to fill `rootScope` with unnecessary objects, but if you are watching for some variable which is used in entire application such as current user's attribute, I guess it would make sense to put `$watch` expression into `$rootScope`.